# EntityFramework lazy loading is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i'm new to EntityFramework 6 and keep on problem in POCO.

Following is my code

**Domain.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public long UserRoleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual _EntityUserRole UserRole { get; set; }    
}

public class UserRole : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<_EntityUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<_EntityUserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }

    internal _EntityUserRole()
    {
        Users = new List<_EntityUser>();
        UserPermissions = new List<_EntityUserPermission>();
    }
}

public class UserPermission : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<_EntityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    internal _EntityUserPermission()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<_EntityUserRole>();
    }
}
```

**Mapping.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseEntityMap<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntityMap()
    {
        ToTable(typeof(T).Name);
        HasKey(a => a.Id);
    }
}

public class UserMap : BaseEntityMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
        : base()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.UserRole)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserRoleId);
    }
}

public class UserRoleMap : BaseEntityMap<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleMap()
        : base()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.UserPermissions)
            .WithMany(x => x.UserRoles)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("UserRoleId");
                x.MapRightKey("UserPermissionId");
                x.ToTable("_EntityUserRole_UserPermission");
            });
    }
}

public class UserPermissionMap : BaseEntityMap<UserPermission>
{
    public UserPermissionMap()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

**SqlServerDataContext.cs**

```
internal class SqlServerDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }

    public SqlServerDataContext()
        : base("Name=MyDB")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserPermissionMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        using (SqlServerDataContext ctx = new SqlServerDataContext())
        {
            UserRole role = new UserRole();
            role.Name = "Super";

            UserPermission prm1 = new UserPermission();
            prm1.Name = "Delete";
            role.UserPermissions.Add(prm1);

            UserPermission prm2 = new UserPermission();
            prm2.Name = "Add";
            role.UserPermissions.Add(prm2);

            UserPermission prm3 = new UserPermission();
            prm3.Name = "Edit";
            role.UserPermissions.Add(prm3);

            User user = new User();
            user.Name = "User 1";
            user.UserRole = role;

            ctx.Users.Add(user);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (SqlServerDataContext ctx = new SqlServerDataContext())
        {
            var b = ctx.Users.Find(1);
        }
    }
```

**Result**
[image: user]
[image: retrieve]

As in print screen, after i insert a record into **User** and when i retrieve back the **UserPermissions** is empty. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `SaveChanges()` after you add the models to the collections so that they are persisted to the database.

Then you can read from the database what you need.

After that you need to access that Property or use the Include (to make it eager, which is prefered usage).

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (SqlServerDataContext ctx = new SqlServerDataContext())
    {
        UserRole role = new UserRole();
        role.Name = "Super";

        UserPermission prm1 = new UserPermission();
        prm1.Name = "Delete";
        role.UserPermissions.Add(prm1);

        UserPermission prm2 = new UserPermission();
        prm2.Name = "Add";
        role.UserPermissions.Add(prm2);

        UserPermission prm3 = new UserPermission();
        prm3.Name = "Edit";
        role.UserPermissions.Add(prm3);

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        User user = new User();
        user.Name = "User 1";
        user.UserRole = role;

        ctx.Users.Add(user);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (SqlServerDataContext ctx = new SqlServerDataContext())
    {
        var b = ctx.Users.Find(1);

        // Method 1
        var roleName = b.UserRole.Name;

        // Method 2
        ctx.Users.Include(x => x.UserRole).Include(x => x.UserRole.UserPermissions).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i can get the **UserRole** but couldn't get the **UserPermission**.

Comment: I updated the answer, there is an extra `Include` in my example! @KelvinGo

Comment: i do add **using System.Data.Entity** but i get this error, `Error 7 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WinForm.User>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WinForm.User>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` @No1_Melman

Comment: Yeah that would be because the `DbSet` has this `Find` method on it, but when you start using `Include` you are changing the return type to `IQueryable<T>`. So you need to use `FirstOrDefault` see my updated